# Python: how to randomly extend entries in a list?

Tags: python, list, extend

Suppose we have a list `l = [0,3,2]`. I want to extend it with the same values in a random way, so `l = [0,3,2,2,0]`

Comment: Extend by how much?

Comment: Extend by a number `n`

Comment: something like `l.extend(random.sample(l, n))` will work

Comment: only works if n < len(l), right?

Comment: be aware that if you do this more than once, it could skew towards certain values.  For example, if you do `l.extend(random.sample(l, 1))` and end up with `[0, 3, 2, 0]`, if you do it again, you have a 50% chance of getting `[0, 3, 2, 0, 0]`.  To avoid this behavior, generate a set of the values first.  `s = set(l)`.  Then extend the list like `l.extend(random.sample(s, n))`

Comment: If you want to extend the list with replacement or with more values than it contains initially, look into the [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) function, new in 3.6  I don't have any experience with it personally but it might be what you want

Comment: @PatrickHaugh oh, man. I didn't realize that had been added to `random`. that's very convenient. I've been using `numpy` to do the same thing!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) or [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) functions to generate extra elements (the latter is available in Python 3.6+). Then use `list.extend()` to add the elements to the list:

```
>>> import random
>>> lst, n = [0, 3, 2], 2
>>> extra = random.choices(lst, k=n)  # or [random.choice(lst) for _ in range(n)]
>>> lst.extend(extra)
>>> lst
[0, 3, 2, 0, 3]
```

Comment: you can drop the `[]` and use generator comprehension instead, it'll be faster

Comment: Not necessarily. This would depend on the size of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Consider something like this:

```
import random
l = [1, 2, 3]
n = 2
for _ in range(n):
    l.append(random.choice(l))
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre don't use a list-comprehension with side-effects *at all*!

Answer (score 0):

*If we want to insert random number at random index, we can use insert function of list*.

```
>>> import random
>>> l = [0,3,2]
>>> n = 10
>>> for i in range(2,n):
        l.insert(random.randrange(i),random.randrange(i))  
>>> print l
[0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2]
```